# Tableau using excel as a data source

Tags: tableau-api

I've a tableau workbook using excel as a data source. The excel uses lots for formulae inside and takes input parameters using cells on a particular worksheet. The issue is I want to input these parameters through Tableau, get the excel refreshed on the backend and show the output of the excel in Tableau. Any suggestions how can I accomplish this? Thanks much in advance

Comment: Tableau does not write to data sources. Only connects to them for visualization.

Comment: You will need to write back the same logic to tableau. You would not be using excel anymore but only as a source of data

Answer (score 0):

You can create parameters in Tableau. The Excel calculations using these parameters would also need to move into Tableau as Calculated Fields. Basically you would pull the raw Excel data into Tableau and perform calculations there using your Tableau parameters.